# Pytest collection with parametrized session fixture

Tags: pytest

I'm having some trouble understanding pytest collects fixtures and tests, and the order that everything is executed, specifically with pytest fixtures that have `params=[]` passed in.

I want to share this example, and my logic.

Say I have 3 apps, `App1`, `App2`, `app3`, and for each App, I execute SampleSuite. SampleSuite has 1 class scoped fixture that will sign some random user in. And before each test in the test suite, there is a function scoped fixture which will perform some navigation.
This is achieved below with this sample `test_sample.py` and a basic `pytest.ini` file (for logging)

```
import logging
import pytest

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["App1", "App2", "App3"])
def apps_fixture(request):
    """ Sets up some generic app """
    logger.info(f"Setting up for app {request.param}")
    yield
    logger.info(f"Tearing down for app {request.param}")


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("apps_fixture", "testsuite_user_fixture", "testcase_navigation_fixture")
class TestSampleSuite:
    """ Sample Suite """
    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def testsuite_user_fixture(cls):
        """ fixture executed once for the test suite """
        logger.info("Setting up testsuite_user_fixture to sign a random user in")
        yield
        logger.info("Tearing down testsuite_user_fixture to sign the user out")

    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
    def testcase_navigation_fixture(cls):
        """ fixture executed before each test case """
        logger.info("Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation")
        yield
        logger.info("Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture")

    def test_sample_1(self):
        """
        A test case
        """
        logger.info("Test3")
```

Now, when I run this test above, the order of the ouput is as follows...

```
test_apps.py::TestSampleSuite::test_sample_1[App1] 
--------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Setting up for app App1
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Setting up testsuite_user_fixture to sign a random user in
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation
---------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Test3
PASSED                                                                      [ 33%]
-------------------------------- live log teardown --------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture

test_apps.py::TestSampleSuite::test_sample_1[App2] 
--------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Tearing down for app App1
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Setting up for app App2
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation
---------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Test3
PASSED                                                                      [ 66%]
-------------------------------- live log teardown --------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture

test_apps.py::TestSampleSuite::test_sample_1[App3] 
--------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Tearing down for app App2
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Setting up for app App3
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation
---------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Test3
PASSED                                                                      [100%]
-------------------------------- live log teardown --------------------------------
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Tearing down testsuite_user_fixture to sign the user out
2020-09-01 15:48:59 INFO Tearing down for app App3
```

From what I see in this output, the session scope fixture `apps_fixture` gets set up and torn down for each parameter passed (as expected) but the class scope fixture `testsuite_user_fixture` only gets set up and torn down once for the entire run. (This is the confusing part for me)

What I was expecting, is that the `testsuite_user_fixture` would be set up and torn down for each parameter that is passed since class is a smaller scope than session.

As for my investigation, I did not find much help on pytest docs or around google.
What I did find is that using pytests `--collect-only` shares some interesting details. After running `pytest test_apps.py --collect-only` the structure that is collected looks like this...

```
<Module test_apps.py>
  <Class TestSampleSuite>
      <Function test_sample_1[App1]>
      <Function test_sample_1[App2]>
      <Function test_sample_1[App3]>
```

This gives me some insight to why the class fixture is only set up and torn down once per param, but I dont under stand why. And I tried to debug this and understand how pytest collects all of this, but I got lost in a jungle of hooks.

NOTE: The `testsuite_user_fixture` work correctly if I have 2 or more classes during the test run, because each class will run before moving to the next parameter from `apps_fixture`. So the issue only arrises when running 1 test class.

I couldnt find great documentation on pytest for fixtures that pass in parameters, so I was hoping to find some help here. So my question is...
Is it possible to run the class scoped fixture per parameter that is passed for a session scope fixture?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but easy to answer: You need to specify the dependencies of the fixtures.

The `testsuite_user_fixture` fixture is not dependent on `apps_fixture` and therefore does not need to tear down. If you want a fixture to tear down before a higher level fixture, you need to add it to its dependencies. For example `def testsuite_user_fixture(cls, apps_fixture)`.

Here my changes:

```py
import logging
import pytest

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["App1", "App2", "App3"])
def apps_fixture(request):
    """ Sets up some generic app """
    logger.info(f"Setting up for app {request.param}")
    yield
    logger.info(f"Tearing down for app {request.param}")


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("apps_fixture", "testsuite_user_fixture", "testcase_navigation_fixture")
class TestSampleSuite:
    """ Sample Suite """
    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def testsuite_user_fixture(cls, apps_fixture):
        """ fixture executed once for the test suite """
        logger.info("Setting up testsuite_user_fixture to sign a random user in")
        yield
        logger.info("Tearing down testsuite_user_fixture to sign the user out")

    @classmethod
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
    def testcase_navigation_fixture(cls):
        """ fixture executed before each test case """
        logger.info("Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation")
        yield
        logger.info("Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture")

    def test_sample_1(self):
        """
        A test case
        """
        logger.info("Test3")
```

And here the logs:

```bash
$ python -m pytest test_delete.py -o log_cli=true --log-level=INFO
============================================================= test session starts =============================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.11, pytest-7.3.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/borja/projects/deepaas_full
configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: typeguard-2.13.3, dvc-3.1.0, hydra-core-1.3.2, mock-3.11.1, anyio-3.7.0, xdist-3.3.1, env-0.8.2, cov-4.1.0
collected 3 items                                                                                                                             

test_delete.py::TestSampleSuite::test_sample_1[App1] 
--------------------------------------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:9 Setting up for app App1
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:21 Setting up testsuite_user_fixture to sign a random user in
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:29 Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation
---------------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:37 Test3
PASSED                                                                                                                                  [ 33%]
-------------------------------------------------------------- live log teardown --------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:31 Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture

test_delete.py::TestSampleSuite::test_sample_1[App2] 
--------------------------------------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:23 Tearing down testsuite_user_fixture to sign the user out
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:11 Tearing down for app App1
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:9 Setting up for app App2
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:21 Setting up testsuite_user_fixture to sign a random user in
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:29 Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation
---------------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:37 Test3
PASSED                                                                                                                                  [ 66%]
-------------------------------------------------------------- live log teardown --------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:31 Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture

test_delete.py::TestSampleSuite::test_sample_1[App3] 
--------------------------------------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:23 Tearing down testsuite_user_fixture to sign the user out
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:11 Tearing down for app App2
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:9 Setting up for app App3
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:21 Setting up testsuite_user_fixture to sign a random user in
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:29 Setting up testcase_navigation_fixture for navigation
---------------------------------------------------------------- live log call ----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:37 Test3
PASSED                                                                                                                                  [100%]
-------------------------------------------------------------- live log teardown --------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:31 Tearing down testcase_navigation_fixture
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:23 Tearing down testsuite_user_fixture to sign the user out
INFO     test_delete:test_delete.py:11 Tearing down for app App3


============================================================== 3 passed in 0.01s ==============================================================
```